# Invalid dump format pgbackups:restore even with Dropbox download link

Tags: postgresql, heroku, dropbox

I'm trying to transfer data from my local postgresql dump file to a Heroku database. 
I've been trying to use pgbackups:restore using the tips I found in SO but this error below is a brick-wall: "INVALID DUMP FORMAT HTML document text". I think the problem definitely lies in dropbox.

I try to copy the URL From this Dropbox screen (the link on the Download button), after clicking the "Share" link. But the 'Invalid Dump Format HTML document text' error shown below is persisting. I've tried different permutations of the URL (https www, https dl, http www ... they all give me the same errors)

[image]

$ heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE_URL 'https://dl.dropbox.com/s/80vy8mm6enwsdfo/mydb.dump'

> HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLUE_URL (DATABASE_URL)  <---restore---  mydb.dump
>
> !    WARNING: Destructive Action  !    This command will affect the
>   app: terrysquotes  !    To proceed, type "appName" or re-run this
>   command with --confirm appName

$ appName

> Retrieving... done
>
> !    An error occurred and your restore did not finish.  !    Please
>   run `heroku logs --ps pgbackups` for details.

$ heroku logs --ps pgbackups

> 2014-06-22T16:44:11+00:00 app[pgbackups]: psql: bin//pg-latest/psql
>   2014-06-22T16:44:11+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   --------+------+------+------ 2014-06-22T16:44:11+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pg_restore: env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin//9.3
>   bin//9.3/pg_restore 2014-06-22T16:44:12+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Invalid
>   dump format: /tmp/4XHVprPkdu/mydb.dump: HTML document text
>   2014-06-22T16:44:12+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: done
>   2014-06-22T16:44:11+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Started:  Sun Jun 22
>   16:44:11 UTC 2014 2014-06-22T16:44:11+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   download_progress: start 2014-06-22T16:44:12+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   download_progress: 486.0bytes 2014-06-22T16:44:11+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: Location:
>   0d306785-c6e9-42a6-ab66-3fb55f7f0f6e:/tmp/4XHVprPkdu
>   2014-06-22T16:44:11+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  Schema | Name | Type | Info
>   2014-06-22T16:45:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]: psql: bin//pg-latest/psql
>   2014-06-22T16:45:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress:  496B
>   2014-06-22T16:45:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]: (0 rows)
>   2014-06-22T16:45:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  Schema | Name | Type | Info
>   2014-06-22T16:45:38+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Location:
>   41095e94-2a25-42c5-a778-0f37d6d0fbd9:/tmp/bI1zFet590
>   2014-06-22T16:45:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: start
>   2014-06-22T16:45:38+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Started:  Sun Jun 22
>   16:45:38 UTC 2014 2014-06-22T16:45:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   2014-06-22T16:45:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pg_restore: env
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin//9.3 bin//9.3/pg_restore 2014-06-22T16:45:39+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: --------+------+------+------
>   2014-06-22T16:45:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pv: bin//pv-latest
>   2014-06-22T16:45:40+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress:
>   496.0bytes 2014-06-22T16:45:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]: 2014-06-22T16:45:40+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Invalid dump format:
>   /tmp/bI1zFet590/mydb.dump: HTML document text
>   2014-06-22T16:45:40+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: done
>   2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00 app[pgbackups]: 2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: psql: bin//pg-latest/psql 2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: download_progress: 226.0bytes
>   2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pg_restore: env
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin//9.3 bin//9.3/pg_restore 2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: download_progress: done 2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: pv: bin//pv-latest 2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]:  Schema | Name | Type | Info 2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: Invalid dump format: /tmp/wahMuTNOLf/mydb.dump: HTML
>   document text 2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Started:  Sun
>   Jun 22 16:47:32 UTC 2014 2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress:  226B
>   2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: start
>   2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Location:
>   3a91ccfa-a2c0-4277-b84b-d2be43e4a834:/tmp/wahMuTNOLf
>   2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00 app[pgbackups]: (0 rows)
>   2014-06-22T16:47:32+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   --------+------+------+------ 2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00 app[pgbackups]: psql: bin//pg-latest/psql 2014-06-22T16:50:49+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: download_progress: done 2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: Location:
>   ff26e7c9-51b1-49a9-8eac-96380e518059:/tmp/e940S4ziPp
>   2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   --------+------+------+------ 2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress:  486B 2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]:  Schema | Name | Type | Info 2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: download_progress: start 2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: Started:  Sun Jun 22 16:50:48 UTC 2014
>   2014-06-22T16:50:49+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress:
>   486.0bytes 2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pg_restore: env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin//9.3 bin//9.3/pg_restore 2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: 2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pv: bin//pv-latest
>   2014-06-22T16:50:48+00:00 app[pgbackups]: (0 rows)
>   2014-06-22T16:50:49+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Invalid dump format:
>   /tmp/e940S4ziPp/mydb.dump: HTML document text
>   2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   --------+------+------+------ 2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress:  386B 2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: Started:  Sun Jun 22 16:53:27 UTC 2014
>   2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pg_restore: env
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin//9.3 bin//9.3/pg_restore 2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: 2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   download_progress: 386.0bytes 2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: Location:
>   44aaa82b-b329-4ea8-b869-af74a2291d2d:/tmp/ar3nXH75CR
>   2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  Schema | Name | Type | Info
>   2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: start
>   2014-06-22T16:53:28+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Invalid dump format:
>   /tmp/ar3nXH75CR/mydb.dump: HTML document text
>   2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00 app[pgbackups]: psql: bin//pg-latest/psql
>   2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00 app[pgbackups]: 2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: pv: bin//pv-latest 2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: (0 rows) 2014-06-22T16:53:27+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   download_progress: done 2014-06-22T17:01:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   download_progress: start 2014-06-22T17:01:38+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pv:
>   bin//pv-latest 2014-06-22T17:01:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   download_progress:  486B 2014-06-22T17:01:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   --------+------+------+------ 2014-06-22T17:01:38+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Started:  Sun Jun 22 17:01:38 UTC 2014
>   2014-06-22T17:01:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pg_restore: env
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin//9.3 bin//9.3/pg_restore 2014-06-22T17:01:39+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: 2014-06-22T17:01:38+00:00 app[pgbackups]: psql:
>   bin//pg-latest/psql 2014-06-22T17:01:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]:  Schema
>   | Name | Type | Info 2014-06-22T17:01:3 9+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   download_progress: 486.0bytes 2014-06-22T17:01:39+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: download_progress: done 2014-06-22T17:01:38+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: Location:
>   aa3c5322-1899-4811-b74e-fff91218fc6c:/tmp/wqC9ziSvIA
>   2014-06-22T17:01:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]: 2014-06-22T17:01:39+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: (0 rows) 2014-06-22T17:01:39+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   Invalid dump format: /tmp/wqC9ziSvIA/mydb.dump: HTML document text
>   2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00 app[pgbackups]: psql: bin//pg-latest/psql
>   2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: start
>   2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00 app[pgbackups]: 2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: Location:
>   d5f20719-b1b1-4a8f-9e92-bb45d19a5479:/tmp/S2eb3hRqgP
>   2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pg_restore: env
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=bin//9.3 bin//9.3/pg_restore 2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: (0 rows) 2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
>   Started:  Sun Jun 22 17:01:56 UTC 2014 2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: pv: bin//pv-latest 2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]:  Schema | Name | Type | Info 2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: --------+------+------+------
>   2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress:  386B
>   2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00 app[pgbackups]: 2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00
>   app[pgbackups]: download_progress: 386.0bytes
>   2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00 app[pgbackups]: download_progress: done
>   2014-06-22T17:01:56+00:00 app[pgbackups]: Invalid dump format:
>   /tmp/S2eb3hRqgP/mydb.dump: HTML document text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/80vy8mm6enwsdfo/mydb.dump. See https://www.dropbox.com/help/201/en for details.